# Move a player along Y axis using touch location

Tags: c#, android, unity3d-2dtools

I'm trying to move a player when the screen is tapped to where the screen is tapped, but only along the Y axis. I've tried this:

```
Vector2 touchPosition;
        [SerializeField] float speed = 1f;   

void Update() {

            for (var i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; i++) {

                if (Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Began) {

                    // assign new position to where finger was pressed
                    transform.position = new Vector3 (transform.position.x, Input.GetTouch(i).position.y, transform.position.z);

                }
            }    
        }
```

But the player disappears rather than moves. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the touch position from Screen to World. This is very easy to do, I've just knocked this quick script together, hopefully it helps:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TouchSomething : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public GameObject thingToMove;

    public float smooth = 2;

    private Vector3 _endPosition;

    private Vector3 _startPosition;

    private void Awake()
    {
        _startPosition = thingToMove.transform.position;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if(Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android || Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer)
        {
            _endPosition = HandleTouchInput();
        }
        else
        {
            _endPosition = HandleMouseInput();
        }

        thingToMove.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(thingToMove.transform.position, new Vector3(_endPosition.x, _endPosition.y, 0), Time.deltaTime * smooth);
    }

    private Vector3 HandleTouchInput()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; i++) 
        {
            if (Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Began) 
            {
                var screenPosition = Input.GetTouch(i).position;
                _startPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(screenPosition);
            }
        }

        return _startPosition;
    }

    private Vector3 HandleMouseInput()
    {
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            var screenPosition = Input.mousePosition;
            _startPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(screenPosition);
        }

        return _startPosition;
    }
}
```

This allows you to also test in the editor as well.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thats brilliant it works perfect thanks. So would there be a way to make this movement smooth rather than isntant? So say the player moves to the touch location over half a second?

Comment: Yup, I would take a look at using Lerp to achieve this, you can see a tutorial using it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cD-mXwSCvWc

Comment: Thankyou for your help :)

Comment: I've checked out the tutorial, and from what I understand the .Lerp needs to go in the Update() so I put this code: thingToMove.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (_worldPosition.x, _worldPosition.y, 0);  Its throwing an error, I guess because it doesn't say new Vector 3. .Lerp isn't recognised with new Vector 3 though, so any ideas??

Comment: I've updated the answer to include lerping to a new position. Hope this helps ^_^